How to filter out elements with No Value for certain field
I have a list of Events in Python. The problem i have is that a lot of events don't contain an event_data['pick']['blurb']. How do I create a filtered list with just the events that have this data?
Current code shows error
    if event["event"]['pick']['blurb'] in events:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

with open(output_file, "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["Event name", "Date", "Start Time", "End Time",
                     "Artists", "Images", "Image", "Blurb", "Venue"])

    filtered = []
    for event in events:
        if event["event"]['pick']['blurb'] in events:
            filtered.append(event)
            # print(filtered)
            
    

    for event in filtered:
        event_data = event["event"]
        writer.writerow([event_data['title'],
                         event_data['date'],
                         event_data['startTime'],
                         event_data['endTime'],
                         ', '.join([artist['name'] for artist in event_data['artists']]),
                         ', '.join([images['filename'] for images in event_data['images']]),
                         event_data['images'][0]['filename'],
                         **event_data['pick']['blurb'],**
                         event_data['venue']['name']])

Solution i used : See below in comments
try:
except (TypeError, IndexError):
pass

Which value is None? event["event"] or event["event"]["pick"]? Add a check for that in the if condition.

if event["event"]["pick"] and event["event"]['pick']['blurb'] in events:

Yes it should be flitered but the issue is still before that. I suppose im asking how do i add that check. Im new to Python. Do you have an example please?

Ill try that. Thanks

Are you sure the condition you're checking is correct? A blurb sounds like a string, but events is a list of dictionaries.

So what if blurb in events: will never be true.

The error doesn't say that event_data['pick']['blurb'] doesn't exist. It says that event_data['pick'] is None, not a dictionary.

There are a few solutions (This is assuming that your code is doing what you want it to do and that's the only error you need help with).
The easiest way (but probably not the best way) is to just ignore the events that give an error using try: and except: (you can probably assume the ones that don't work don't have a ["pick"]["blurb"]). This is usually only used as a temporary fix but if there's nothing else that could possibly go wrong, try and except should be good as a permanent fix.
#this is the line that gives you the error when you check if the ['event']['pick']['blurb'] is in events, but we put it inside a try and except
try:
    if event['event']['pick']['blurb'] in events:
        filtered.append(event)
except TypeError:
    pass #Do nothing when the event doesn't have a ['pick']['blurb'] and causes and error. You can also use "continue" instead of "pass", which just moves on to the next loop

The next easiest way would be to implement conditional checks to see if it's not None in the first place, because as your error says, NoneType object is not subscriptable and in this case that means you're looking for something that doesn't exist. We do this by using .get(), which should return the value unless it doesn't exist, in which case it should return None.
#Same place as last example but we do an additional conditional check
if event.get('event') != None and event['event'].get('pick') != None and event['event']['pick'].get('blurb') != None:
    filtered.append(event)


In the end i figured out if i just leave out the if but use the try with except (TypeError, IndexError): it covers everything so much appreciated.
